# Import Github package in go

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go

[image: This is how go.mod looks like]I'm trying out AWS Lambda in go and have the following imports.

```
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ssm"
  )
```

Among these I'm unable to resolve the import for package aws-sdk-go. It always suggests to create such directory in GOPATH:/src.
Here's what I have tried so far:

1. Checked GOPATH is right.
2. I also did `go mod vendor` which resulted in vendor directory in my project and it has aws-sdk-go under it
3. Did go get `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go` and this downloaded this sdk to my GOPATH and it looks like this `pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.44.138/aws`
4. When I try to use `pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.44.138/aws` in my import, it complains that there cannot be `@` in import.

I don't get why it doesn't refer to the package in vendor directory just like the other import `github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda`

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Use modules, do not use GOPATH, do not use vendoring. Show actual command you typed in the console with actual error output.

Comment: @Volker Followed the blog on modules https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules
and tried the same.
All I see are that the certain imports are not resolved, like the `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go`

Comment: Do not post images of text. What does "imports are not resolved" _mean_. Show the command you type end the error printed.

Comment: To your point number `4.`, the error's correct, `mymod@v1.2.3/mypkg` is not a valid import path. You can only use major versions in import paths and the required format is: `...mymod/mypkg/v2`; but you can use that only for versions 2 and up, versions below 2 must not use a version suffix.

Comment: I changed import to `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws` and did `go build` and see no error. 

It's just the code base is all RED and doesn't show suggestions on available methods from this package or if the code written is actually correct. It's difficult to differentiate whether it's an actual error or just some things in import is messed up.

Comment: So you are having trouble with your IDE, not your code?

Comment: yes, that's what I realized since build shows no error

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comments above, the issue was not with go code itself but the IDE.
I use IntelliJ and had GOPATH set and Module integration disabled.
To resolve the issue I removed GOPATH and enabled Module integration.

To understand Modules this blog helped me: https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules